# Zend 2: How to change template for specific action?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm looking for a way to change view template (NOT layout), but I don't have access to this module (it's part of vendor), so I can't do:

```
$view = new ViewModel();
$view->setTemplate($template);
```

It would be nice if I could do it by attaching to some event.

I have try following code:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
        $controller      = $e->getTarget();
        $routeMatch      = $e->getRouteMatch();
        $routeName       = $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();
        if ($routeName === 'login') {
            $controller->layout('layout/layout');
            $e->getViewModel()->setTemplate('views/login');
        }
    }, 1);
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
}
```

But it seems like it doesn't work that way. I mean, it changed my layout, it changed my view template, but when I try for example:
`$this->form` I get `null`. Looks like this way is clearing all variables from that action.

Any way how to make it working?

Comment: How do you set your variables in your controller to the view ?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace a template from other library to your template. Need to setup your module after module from library in a config file `config/application.config.php`.

```
'modules' => array(
    'VendorModule',
    'YourModule'
);
```

In a view manager config need change path to your template for template name of other library.

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'vendor/library/template_name' => __DIR__ . '/your_template.phtml',
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In specific action you can switch the default layout:

```
 $this->layout('layout/your-second-layout');
```

this is only for the layout to change in a specific action.